# SQL query to find Employees Skiils,Companies and projects

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my ER diagram : [image]

Actually I tried to write it with recursive CTE but I did not succeed
I was wondering If you could help me with that
Thank you

Sample Data

EmployeeInfo:

```
EmployeeID   FirstName
---------   ---------
  1            A
  2            B
```

Skill:

```
SkillID   SkillName
--------  ---------
  1         Java
  2         Python
  3          CSS
```

Company:

```
CompanyID    CompanyName
---------    -----------
   1             X
   2             Y
```

Project :

```
Projectcode   ProjectDesc
----------    ------------
1                GTHY
2                GYHU
```

I need to write a query to give me this result (The Expected Result)

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName   Skills       Companies     Projects 
---------   ------------   ------       ---------     ---------

   1           A        Java,Python,Css    X,Y            GTHY
```

I mean The EmployeeID and Name , His skills , Companies he had worked on and projects he had participated in

Comment: Please update your question to include table definitions, sample data for each table and expected results from your query - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Lots of problems like this fall into [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Give that article a read and see if it helps you out.

Comment: I think It can be solved with recursive CTE , But i have problem writing it . even if we write the recursive CTE using row-number and write it for only one column (company) it is good . I can expand it

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, not sure what you mean. How does the question relate to relational division?

Comment: @PTTT Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this types of problems with a simple "For XML Path" clause in sql.
You can do this by:

```
SELECT
E.EmployeeID,
E.FirstName+' '+E.LastName AS EmployeeName,
(
    SELECT SkillName+', ' FROM Skill WHERE SkillID IN
    (
        SELECT SkillID FROM EmployeeSkill WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    ) FOR XML PATH('')
) AS Skills,
(
    SELECT Name+', ' FROM Company WHERE CompanyID IN (
        SELECT CompanyID FROM EmployeeCompany WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    ) FOR XML PATH('')
) AS Companies,
(
    SELECT ProjectName+', ' FROM Project WHERE ProjectID IN
    (
        SELECT Project FROM EmployeeProject WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    ) FOR XML PATH('')
) AS Projects
FROM EmployeeInfo AS E
```

**UPDATE**

You can try this to remove comma(,) at last of skills, companies & project..

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
EmployeeName,
left(Skills,LEN(Skills)-1) AS Skills,
left(Companies,LEN(Companies)-1) AS Companies,
left(Projects,LEN(Projects)-1) AS Projects
FROM(
    SELECT E.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID, E.FirstName+' '+E.LastName AS EmployeeName,
    (
        SELECT SkillName+', ' FROM Skill WHERE SkillID IN
        (
            SELECT SkillID FROM EmployeeSkill WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
        ) FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Skills,
    (
        SELECT Name+', ' FROM Company WHERE CompanyID IN
        (
            SELECT CompanyID FROM EmployeeCompany WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
        ) FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Companies,
    (
        SELECT ProjectName+', ' FROM Project WHERE ProjectID IN
        (
            SELECT Project FROM EmployeeProject WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
        ) FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Projects
    FROM EmployeeInfo AS E
) AS Tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_concat()` and `sub-queries` to get your desired result.

In the following query you will get your desired result

`EmployeeId   = e.id` (id of employee)
`EmployeeName = e.name` (name of the employee)
`Skills       = skills` (all skill that employee have)
`Companies    = companies` (all companies in which employee is working/worked)
`Projects     = projects` (all projects in which employee's company participeted)

```
select
    e.id,
    e.name,
    (
        select GROUP_CONCAT(s.name)
        from skill s left join employee_skill es on es.skill_id = s.id
        where es.employee_id = e.id
    ) as skills,
    (
        select GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)
        from company c left join employee_company ec on ec.company_id = c.id
        where ec.employee_id = e.id
    )as companies,
    (
        select GROUP_CONCAT(p.name)
        from project p left join company_project cp on cp.project_id = p.id
        where cp.company_id in(
            select id from employee_company where employee_company.employee_id = e.id
        )
    )as projects
from employee_info e
```

**UPDATE**

Same task in `SQL SERVER`

```
    select
        e.id,
        e.name,
        skills = stuff((
            SELECT ',' + s.name
            from skill s left join employee_skill es on es.skill_id = s.id
            where es.employee_id = e.id
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''),
        companies = stuff((
            SELECT ',' + c.name
            from company c left join employee_company ec on ec.company_id = c.id
            where ec.employee_id = e.id
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''),
        projects = stuff((
            SELECT ',' + p.name
            from project p left join company_project cp on cp.project_id = p.id
            where cp.company_id in(
                select id from employee_company where employee_company.employee_id = e.id
            )
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
    from employee_info e
```